# LinkedIn API get metrics for profile Update

Tags: linkedin-api

User in my system uses a LinkedIn App to publish posts in user's LinkedIn profile after they grant access to my system using OAuth connection.

How can I get metrics (like how many "likes" the post has) for all the posts published?

So far I only found this available for "Companies", not common users.